# How to extract all string matches from a column using a input corpus/list in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nltk, text-mining

For example I have the below list of strings as input corpus (actually its a big list with 100 values).
action=['jump','fly','run','swim']

Data contains a column called action_description. How can I extract all the string matches in the action_description using action list as input corpus?

Note: I have already done lemmitization description_action, so if the column have words like jumping or jumped its already converted to jump.

***Sample input & output***

```
"I love to run and while my friend prefer to swim" --> "run swim"
"Allan excels at high jump but he is not a good at running" --> "jump run"
```

Note: I found the below pandas function but its not well documentated so couldnt figure out how to use it.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html

Please recommend a optimal solution since by input dataframe have 200K rows.

EDIT
Words like jumper & runway should be ignore by the algorithm i.e. should not be classified as jump & run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Steps:***

1. We perform lemmatization only on verbs by supplying `pos='v'` and let the nouns remain as they were before by iterating thorugh each word in that list got by `str.split` operation.
2. Then, take all the matches of words present in the lookup list and the lemmatized list using `set`.
3. Finally, join them to return string as the output.

---

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

action = ['jump','fly','run','swim']     # lookup list
lem = WordNetLemmatizer() 
fcn = lambda x: " ".join(set([lem.lemmatize(w, 'v') for w in x]).intersection(set(action)))
df['action_description'] = df['action_description'].str.split().apply(fcn)
df
```

[image]

---

Starting `DF` used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(action_description=["I love to run and while my friend prefer to swim", 
                                           "Allan excels at high jump but he is not a good at running"]))
```

---

To generate binary flags (0/1), we can use [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) method by splitting strings on whitespace and computing it's indicator variables as shown:

```
bin_flag = df['action_description'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').add_suffix('_flag')
pd.concat([df['action_description'], bin_flag], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Why is pos='v' i.e. verb used? Will result improve if 1st pos tagging on the sentence is identified and then pos tag is passed to the lemmatize() function?

Comment: Lemmatiser generates real words, but without contextual information it’s not able to distinguish between nouns and verbs. The context is provided by the POS tag(*as all words were in their verb form, pos='v' was used*). Yes, the results would definitely improve if there are words other than verbs in your lookup list, if you could generate POS tags automatically and lemmatize w.r.t that parts of speech.

Comment: Thanks! How can i modify your code to convert words like 'leakage' to 'leak' etc using lemmitization ?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't as it is a pure [***noun form***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leakage). It would have worked if it was "leaking" or something similar. By the way, you could try stemming first to overcome such cases. Like, some stemmers give you different root words that word is derived from. For eg: for this case, you can use Lancaster stemmer - `lanc = LancasterStemmer()`;
`lanc.stem('leakages')` which gives you *leak* as the stemmed output.

Comment: Hi Nickil, For each of the matching values in action list i want to creat binary flag. Eg: jump_flg=1 for match exists in 'action_description' else jump_flg=1. Simillarly for fly_flg, swim_flg etc.

Comment: *See edit*. Aside - Usually answerers don't entertain multiple questions being asked in one post, however related/unrelated it might be to the original question. If you have more questions regarding this, feel free to open a new post and ask over there.

Answer (score 1):

```
action=['jump','fly','run','swim']


str1="I    love to run and while my friend prefer to swim" ##--> "run swim"
str2="Allan excels at high jump but he is not a good at running" ##--> "jump run"

actionDtl=""
for word in str1.split():
    if word in action:
        if actionDtl<>"":
            actionDtl=actionDtl+" " +word
        else:
            actionDtl=actionDtl+word
    else:
        for act in action:
            if word.find(act)>=0:
                if actionDtl<>"":
                    actionDtl=actionDtl+" " +act
                else:
                    actionDtl=actionDtl+act
                break      
print actionDtl
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really a regex problem with using `re.findall` for matching strings and `operator.add`  to combine matches

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import operator as op


action=['jump','fly','run','swim']

str1="I    love to run and while my friend prefer to swim" ##--> "run swim"
str2="Allan excels at high jump but he is not a good at running" ##--> "jump run



df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],
                  'B':['I    love to run and while my friend prefer to swim',
                  'Allan excels at high jump but he is not a good at running',
                  'Ostrich can run very fast but cannot fly',
                  'The runway was wet hence the Jumper flew over it'] })


df['ApproxMatch']=df['B'].apply(lambda x: [reduce(op.add, re.findall(act,x)) for act in action if re.findall(act,x) <> []] )

#using r'\b'+jump+r'\b' to match jump exactly, where \b stands for word boundaries

df['ExactMatch']=df['B'].apply(lambda x: [reduce(op.add, re.findall(r"\b"+act+r"\b",x)) for act in action if re.findall(r"\b"+act+r"\b",x) <> []] )
```

**Output:**

```
df

#   A                                                  B  ApproxMatch  \
#0  1  I    love to run and while my friend prefer to...  [run, swim]   
#1  2  Allan excels at high jump but he is not a good...  [jump, run]   
#2  3           Ostrich can run very fast but cannot fly   [fly, run]   
#3  4   The runway was wet hence the Jumper flew over it        [run]   
#
#    ExactMatch  
#0  [run, swim]  
#1       [jump]  
#2   [fly, run]  
#3           []
```

Note that with exact matching for row 2, "running" is not matched with "run"

Comment: Thanks! What if the description contain words like "Runway" & "Jumper"?

Comment: Added exact matching as well, does it conform with your expectations. Could you update your original post with inputs and output expectations for "Runway" and "Jumper"

Comment: Added the expectations.Thanks for sharing. One recommendation is to perform lemmitization, so that flew & running can be classified correctly like @Nickil Maveli has done.